# Ubuntu firefox not loading pages

Tags: firefox

Using Ubuntu 16.04.2 in VMWare.

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago in a VMWare without any problems. I used Firefox to download STS and Intelij, everything worked.

Today I turn on the virtual machine and Firefox will not load any pages. It just doesn't do anything. Firefox loads but when I type 'google.com' or something in the search bar nothing happens. It doesn't crash, it doesn't try to load anything (no progress bar etc). I also uninstalled Firefox, rebooted (windows habit) and reinstalled it but the result is the same.

So I installed Chromium from the Ubuntu software package manager and it works perfectly.

I am a Linux/Ubuntu noob but it seems to me that this is not normal behaviour. If someone has had the same problem or could help it would be much appreciated :).

Comment: What do you mean by "downloaded and installed Firefox"? FF is installed in Ubuntu by default.

Comment: @Pilot6 You are correct, as I said I'm a linux/ubuntu noob.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @DavidFoerster my question was for a way to fix this, ie make Firefox work again but i found the answer by disabling the Ubuntu Modifications plugin in Firefox (no idea what it does but apparently it doesn't work all that well!)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you wanted to achieve? Even if you succeeded it would be useful for future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'fixed' the problem by disabling the Firefox addon/extension **Ubuntu Modifications**.