# 20.04 - Firefox not rendering or loading pages

Tags: firefox, citrix

My Firefox installation does not load or render any pages, nothing happens when I enter an address.

I have already rebooted multiple times, purged Firefox through aptitude, deleted all files related to Firefox (profiles, the complete .mozilla folder in home, everything else) and reinstalled as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887175/ubuntu-firefox-not-loading-pages). I have started Firefox in safe mode as well.

As far as I can tell the problem started after I used "another" Firefox through my universities Citrix service to be able to access their library catalogue. I had to symbolically link all of the files in the Firefox certificate folder to that of the Citrix client for that client to work, although I've since removed those links as well and it did nothing.

I am really pulling my hairs over this as Firefox is heavily integrated in my workflow and I don't want to switch to Chrome but I also don't want to completely reinstall my laptop as that would mean completely setting up my work environment again too.

After running from terminal with --verbose I get the following errors on shutdown:

```
[Parent 138546, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-ifRHdl/firefox-87.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 138546, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-ifRHdl/firefox-87.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 138546, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-ifRHdl/firefox-87.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 138546, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-ifRHdl/firefox-87.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 138546, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-ifRHdl/firefox-87.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 138546, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-ifRHdl/firefox-87.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
[Parent 138546, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: FileDescriptorSet destroyed with unconsumed descriptors: file /build/firefox-ifRHdl/firefox-87.0+build3/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/file_descriptor_set_posix.cc:19
```

Update: After starting with the -p flag in terminal, I got the following error at start up

```
###!!! [Child][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost


###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
```

Comment: When you say "nothing happens" do you mean you don't even get an error message?

Comment: Nope, just blank window, no reaction whatsoever, no error in terminal if I launch through there, It won't even load the preferences page.

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix, see my enclosed picture for output on terminal

Comment: Please copy text with errors (Control Shift C) and paste into your question (Control V) so we can copy from your question (Control C) and paste into google search engine (Control V). We are unable to paste your screen shot into google search.

Comment: Yes, sorry I've updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After removing the Citrix client the problem was solved. Will report this to citrix

Comment: I had the same problem with icaclient 21.4.0.11 - have u got any response? https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=348798

Comment: This problem seems to appear only when Citrix Workspace is installed with security options. I tried from a fresh install on a virtual machine. During the installation process of the .deb, there is a dialog about installation of application protection component. If I select "yes", the bug appear, if I select "no", there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/68361) the problem can occur when multiple versions of firefox were installed.

First use

```
sudo apt remove firefox
```

Then check the directory `/usr/lib/firefox` and check for leftover files from a different version and manually remove them.

Then resinstall firefox:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

---

Another solution is [turning off multiple-process windows](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1167673):

> You can disable multi-process windows in Firefox by setting these
> `prefs` to false on the about:config page.
>
> - browser.tabs.remote.autostart = false
> - browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 = false
>
> You can open the about:config page: via the location/address bar. You
> can accept the warning and click "I'll be careful" to continue.

Comment: Both of these solutions would not have worked: 1) Already done, even with sudo apt purge, deleting all leftover files, and did nothing as mentioned in OP 2) I couldn't open the about:config page as not even those pages (preferences/stored credentials/...) would load, as mentioned in my answer on your comment.